# Graph Theory, how is E a proper subset of V?

Tags: graph-theory

Given $$V=\{a,b,c\}, E=\{aa,bc\}$$

How is E a proper subset of $V$? Consider $E_n \in E$, when $E_n = aa$ and $aa$ $\not\in V$

Have I said that correct enough?

Edit (source):
[image: source of my issue]

Comment: Where did you see that $E$ is a subset of $V$?

Comment: A book called algorithmic graph theory and sage

Comment: The edge set and vertex set are completely different entities; neither is contained in the other...

Comment: @michael see the edit

Comment: Oh I see now.

$$V^{(2)} = V \times V$$

If you interpret the edge set as ordered pairs from $V \times V$, this idea is immediate.

Comment: So the elements of V are tuples with two elements

Comment: This $V^{(2)}$ ins't defined in the book. Where does that come from?

Comment: @pepsi-maniac Yes, or more simply they are ordered pairs of vertices. This allows the ordered pair (a,a) which means a loop at vertex a. Seems your text abbreviates this ordered pair as simply aa.

Comment: Or does the to the power of 2 mean, given any set n * n. But in this case to the power of its a cartesian product.

Comment: Does that I mean I make arbitary long "to the power" with set theory. Ie $n^{3} = n \times n \times n$

Comment: It is worth emphasizing the difference between *directed* graphs which does use *ordered* pairs of vertices to represent *directed* edges (*who have an orientation on the edges moving "from" the first entry in the pair "to" the second entry*) and standard simple graphs which merely use *size-two sets* of vertices to describe an edge

Comment: As to the question of how to notate the set of (*ordered*) $k$-tuples of a set $A$, yes... that is often written as $A^k$ and is of cardinality $|A|^k$.  Do not confuse the set with it's cardinality, these are different objects.  The set of subsets of $A$ of size $k$ can be notated as $\binom{A}{k}$ and is of cardinality $\binom{|A|}{k}$

Comment: If that is how your author is defining things, they are abusing notation for the sake of readability... which is fine... but not how I would have done it and not how the authors I learned from did it.  Perhaps that is why the author chose to notate it as $V^{(2)}$ as opposed to $V^2$.  In any event, for now it seems you are still focusing on simple graphs and so the nuanced differences I allude to won't matter right away.  Just be warned that eventually it may become important to know the difference and have a way to reconcile the differences in how directed graphs versus graphs are defined.